# Shareholder bullies and doesn't like me. How to deal with this?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, behavior

I have been working for over three years for a really small tech company (about 12 people in the team). This is also my first job ever. I have two bosses, the company owner who works almost always remotely (let's call him John) and a shareholder (let's call him Jack) that had been working with my boss for a long time but had been just a coworker, becoming a shareholder only recently.

I am constantly clashing with Jack: He views me as insubordinate (he himself already said so multiple times). I **always** obey an order coming from him, but sometimes I try different approaches, or make suggestions, or state my opinions, still respecting what he had said. He is highly inquisitive, and if he thinks you're behaving incorrectly, he will expose that by calling you out publicly (for everyone in the office to hear). Whenever someone asks him a question (even through chat), he almost always replies by voice. And many times he will, without even fully reading what you wrote, inquire about your questions, often saying he "did not understand". Most of the time he addresses others with a strong voice tone giving the impression he is rudely correcting you. I find his behavior unprofessional and abusive sometimes. Even if he doesn't intend to make others feel bad, he makes me (and others, probably) feel bad when we are on the receiving end of such behavior.

The problem is that I feel he is harsher with me because he doesn't like my behavior. This led me to do a very bad move out of impulse: I complained about an episode (his behavior) in writing to John. John wrote back and was rather understanding, but told about my complaint to Jack. Jack was furious, and his behavior has grown worse. Last wednesday he nearly insulted my skills, and rudely replied "I have already explained you that" once asked a question.

I believe Jack strongly wants me fired, but John doesn't, and a private discussion between them probably already happened concerning this.

Excluding the obvious escape (leaving the company), how can I deal with him to mitigate his behavior?

**EDIT (2) I am editing here because I am not being honest with myself, even. The real reason why I don't want to leave this job, at least FOR NOW, is because I am aiming for either a programming or database oriented job and I feel having had just a single actual development project is not enough practical knowledge. I want to have more confidence in myself and I feel that comes as I go through more concrete, more valid experiences. **

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53612/discussion-on-question-by-workingbear-shareholder-bullies-and-doesnt-like-me-h).

Answer (score 16):

- **TALK TO THE PERSON FIRST**

Sometimes people are not as unreasonable as we think.  Take this up person to person with Jack before you do anything else.  It could be that he doesn't see his actions as out of line.  If you can end it without getting anyone else involved, that would be the best resolution for all parties concerned.  If you can resolve the issues between yourselves, there's no fear of later retaliation, no difficulties involving others, no need to move on, and no headaches.  Honestly, this has the least likelihood of working, but is a firm foundation of demonstrating that you tried everything should the issue escalate.

- **DOCUMENT EVERYTHING**

Whether you leave or stay, you need to document the behavior of this person, to whom you reported the behavior, what actions were taken after the behavior was reported, as well as any and all follow ups.  If you don't do this and are fired, they will be able to say "fired for cause" and you won't have anything to prove otherwise.

- **MAKE IT KNOWN THAT THE BEHAVIOR IS UNACCEPTABLE.**

Believe it or not, some people don't realize when they are out of line, and that's actually a defense, albeit a weak one.  One of the FIRST questions to be asked if this goes anywhere is "What did [person] say when you confronted him?  It will look very bad for you if you say "Well, I never said anything to him."

Comment: Your third bullet can be excluded in my case. I believe my instincts are pretty good at assessing other people's character. His behavior is questionable with everyone, not just me, which is bad. He sometimes is a nice person, coming up with random jokes that are genuinely fun. But whenever he thinks someone is wrong in some way, he has very bad ways of handling it. I believe he is not aware of how destructive he is, but I also believe he won't be convinced of that and/or consider changing.

Comment: @WorkingBear If he's not aware of how destructive he is, the third paragraph is **most relevant** in your case, and should definitely not be excluded.

Comment: @WorkingBear If he's "sometimes is a nice person, coming up with random jokes that are genuinely fun" then he's likely unaware that his behavior at other times is inappropriate.  Talk to him, preferably when he's in a good mood.

Comment: @Richard U He's only a nice person when he's not under the stress of his work. And I really don't want to approach him given how things are. Thanks to my complaint concerning him, I talked with him in private but we didn't resolve anything. He simply reiterated his claims of me being insubordinate, always with aggressive/rude tone.

Comment: @WorkingBear then you've already gone through bullet point 3, which I said was unlikely to work.  Now, document everything.

Comment: @WorkingBear I don't mean to sound rude, don't get me wrong. But if it's your first job, and the situation has gotten to that point, you probably do not assert very well other people character. Do not assume you do. I could also argue that assuming someone character without talking to them has a very specific name, but discussing that would be off-topic. Just food for thought here.

Comment: This answer is very well-written, but might be improved by telling what to do if (when) bullet point 3 fails. Suggestions from other answers include leaving, keeping a low profile and following up with John.

Comment: @svavil I rearranged the order of my list, I think that should suffice.

Comment: I read a lot about 'document everything'. How one can proof what has been written on a doc (at a court for example)?

Comment: @Fernando yes, I've used this for court, not for employment, but for a dispute with a financial company.  What you do is document every interaction, what the result was, and what the follow-up was.  If you have a private conversation, follow up with an email saying "As per our conversation, you made the following points..."  This **is** evidence and it **will** protect you.

Comment: @RichardU What if the other person answer the email with: "I don't recognize any of this dialog/situations" ?

Comment: @Fernando then you reply.  I'm sorry, could you please clarify what I am misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10):

You essentially have three viable choices

1) Leave. This is probably your best option. There is not a level of pay that is really worth ongoing low level psychological harm. It makes sense to get your resume out there and have options anyway, most likely.

2) Minimize your contact with the bully, keep your head down. Stay out of his way. Do your best job.

3) Give John an ultimatum - say that Jack has to either change his behavior, leave, or you will have to leave. You might want to prepare option (1) above if you are planning this course of action.

Comment: I like your idea of an ultimatum. Him leaving is totally impossible, so it's either he changes his behavior, or I leave. Of course I don't want to do that unless I have another potential employer at hand, though. Regarding psychological harm, it is true, I constantly feel oppressed by this situation, I am constantly "on standby" for something bad happening. Part of this may be due to my overly sensitive nature, I have **great fear** of bad outcomes when relating to others in general.

Comment: It would likely be constructive dismissal which in many jurisdictions would entitle you to unemployment benefits

Comment: Do not blame yourself for an abuser's behavior. Your sensitivity is not the problem. It is healthy to be sensitive to that, it's your mind telling to get away - this is damaging. People who are desensitized to abuse begin to think it is normal and often become abusers themselves.

Comment: @BradThomas AFAIK, there's no notion of "constructive dismissal" in the US. I realize that it does exist in many other countries, but there are a lot of US folks on this site and unfortunately, making work miserable (but not to the point of being hostile) is pretty legal there.

Comment: @WorkingBear don't give an ultimatum if you're not prepared to act upon it.  If you feel that the environment has gotten to the point of being *hostile* and you're in the US, there may be certain legal actions that can be taken if you want to go that far.

Comment: "It's true the OP may have a behavioural trait that encourages harassment from those inclined to give it." I reject your notion that any portion of the responsibility for abuse rests with the victim.

Comment: @alroc I believe there are even slight legal grounds addressing what I have been through, but doing this would only result in me getting fired, which is a bad thing.

Comment: @BradThomas I was never suggesting it. Responsibility lies still with the abuser, but you can shield yourself so you don't suffer from it. If I leave my wallet in plain view in a public place, the thief would still be committing a crime, but I'm ultimately responsible for myself, so I should've taken better care of it. I hope the analogy clarifies my position somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your reasoning:

1. John has promised to get me involved into a very large and important project in the near future

Unspecific promises that something will change.

2. I believe that the nature of my company provides a great insight into business processes.

Trust me; at this stage of your career, EVERY company you work in will be an education for you.

3. It is extremely stressful to me when I need to adapt to new experiences.

And staying isn't stressful? Well, then, you have no problem. Stay at the company until you retire.

4. Getting another job is going to take time.

How do you know? Have you TRIED for any other jobs? Using an 'economic downturn' is a worn-out excuse when you're only looking for one, relatively low level, position.

Stop giving excuses, and go ahead and do something to save your sanity. Neither the company owner nor the shareholder deserve to work with you.

Comment: Any company will be an education for me. That is very true, I agree with that. But I don't want JUST education, I want a quality company that will provide me with quality education. To me, "any company" won't do. I want to strive for great experiences providing me with a LOT of practical knowledge. 

I admit that my reasoning for staying really is somewhat feeble, and I feel the true reason for this reluctance is the one I stated at the chat.

Answer (score 3):

Buy some shares. Evidently, according to the rules at your company, you will then have equal authority with Jack.

As a shareholder, not only will you have the authority to object to the way Jack treats you, you will also be in a position to insist that Jack start treating everybody else with respect too, since high turnover is harmful to the company and therefore to your investment.

Comment: You don't understand the proportion of my company. It's just a room. It makes a lot of money for it's small size. It's not like anyone can go in and become a shareholder, this was due to the decades of working together. And he probably spent quite a sum, that I as a newbie worker, don't have.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the shareholder is also an employee from:

> I have two bosses, the company owner who works almost always remotely (let's call him John) and a shareholder (let's call him Jack) that had been working with my boss for a long time but had been just a coworker, becoming a shareholder only recently.

There are 4 suggestions that come to mind:

1. **Ignore it**: which is what you and your colleagues have done before
2. **Have an informal conversation with the shareholder**: this is unlikely to help as he's already angry and doesn't seem to care about how you feel
3. **Escalate**: you did this with your manager but with no benefit. I would recommend taking documented evidence of how much disruption, in time and monetary terms, this shareholder is causing. Back this up with recommendations too
4. **Find a new job**: which you are reluctant to do

Comment: There is no escalating. The hierarchy is limited to Jack and John (the company owner). I already brought this to John (referring only to a single case, though, I never complained about his overall/usual behavior toward me).

Comment: Taking it to your manager *is* escalating it (above "you and Jack").